# NeVpnManager No VPN shared secret was provided

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vpn, nevpnmanager

Hi I'am trying to create IPSEC VPN connection and connect automatically but it's giving No VPN shared secret was provided error even if I defined shared secret. 
My code likes below and it's saving VPN configuration but doesn't connect.

I'am trying to Add VPN Configuration from my iPhone with same parameters and it's connecting.

```
[[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
[[NEVPNManager sharedManager] loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {



    NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
    p.serverAddress =@"server";
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
    p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;

    NSString *secret = @"secretCode";
    NSData *secretData = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    p.sharedSecretReference=secretData;
    p.localIdentifier=@"identifier";
    p.username=@"username";
    p.passwordReference=[[SSKeychain passwordForService:@"service" account:@"passwordReference"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;


    [NEVPNManager sharedManager].protocolConfiguration=p;

    NSMutableArray *rules = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NEOnDemandRuleConnect *connectRule = [NEOnDemandRuleConnect new];
    [rules addObject:connectRule];
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setOnDemandRules:rules];
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setLocalizedDescription:@"vpn"];

    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];



    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager] saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Save VPN to preference complete");
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
        }

    }];

    NSError *startError;
    [[NEVPNManager sharedManager].connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];
    if(startError) {
        NSLog(@"Start error: %@", startError.localizedDescription);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same error, this example was helpful for me https://github.com/lexrus/VPNOn , I think that you should provide right and valid keychain references in these points:
`p.passwordReference = [VPN user password from keychain];`

`p.sharedSecretReference = [VPN server shared secret from keychain];`